# Graphql server end point calling other api end point from inside it's service method Java springboot

Tags: graphql, apollo-client

Graphql server end point calling other api end point from inside it's service method Java springboot.

I have two end points one calling other to get its data and map it to its own. The first one is a graphql end point and the later is a rest/graphql end point. How to call the later from inside the first graphql project. Is there any client such as  crnk/ kathersis for graphql programmatically.

Answer (score 0):

Checkout the netflix graphQL springboot library. They have open sourced it recently .

[netflix.github.io](https://netflix.github.io/dgs/generating-code-from-schema/#generating-client-apis)

[Open Sourcing the Netflix Domain Graph Service Framework: GraphQL for Spring Boot](https://netflixtechblog.com/open-sourcing-the-netflix-domain-graph-service-framework-graphql-for-spring-boot-92b9dcecda18)